# Hello world program in hla

Tags: assembly, hla

Am getting an error when running HLA code. It's a simple program so I highly doubt the code is at fault.
The error:

```
     POLINK: warning: /SECTION:.bss ignored; section is missing.
```

The code:

```
     program HelloWorld;
     #include("stdlib.hhf")
     begin HelloWorld;
        stdout.put( "Hello, World of Assembly Language", nl );
     end HelloWorld;
```

I am starting assembly language and I need help.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.  Your program doesn't have (or need) a .bss section, since you don't have any zero-initialized static data.  Doesn't it still produce a binary executable you can run?

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, the program runs. It does produce a binary executable. It runs